# Angular component and service communication, didn't share value

Tags: angular

I've got a service, what will get out an id from a form. The next step is that one component call that service. It's okey, but doesn't display the value. It's show "undefined" What will be the problem ? When I click to the button, its shows the message with undefined, not with the id what I want.

**Service:**

```
getCompanyId(company) {
  this.selectedValue = company.id;
  alert("The Selected Company Id" + company.id);
}
```

**Component:**

```
getCompanyIdFromService(company): void {
  this.inputGroupService.getCompanyId(this.company);   
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button mat-stroked-button [value]="company.id" (click)="getCompanyIdFromService(company)">{{company.id}}-{{company.company_name}}</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

pass the url param `company` not the `this.company`

```
this.inputGroupService.getCompanyId(company);
```